# How to limit html file upload to extensionless file?

Tags: html, file, input

I wonder if I can set accept property of HTML's file input to only accept files with no extension?
I mean files like "id_rsa".

Comment: I never understood why people are interested in those old fashioned habit to write a few chars behind a dot in a file name. What is filtering by that meant to achieve?

Comment: @arkascha - well, filtering by that will block close to 100% of the things you want to block. it's extremely rare that people upload a fake file that pretends to be of some type.

Comment: @vsync Well that is probably right for those users who comply. But those are never the problem. The problem are those looking for vulnerable points. And I think we agree that the percentage is different in that case :-) Apart from that it is simply much more efficient and reliable to use server side content validation.

Comment: @arkascha - regardless, one should do both. It's a well known consensus..

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't. The file input is a very limited control. However, nowadays, you have multiple options of writing your own uploader control (without requiring Java, ActiveX etc.), which would allow you to limit the files accepted before starting the upload. You can find quite a few ready scripts, most allowing you to use the usual file input for the upload itself (although Ajax is usually preferred).

If you can't do that, you'll just have to do the validation on the server (very annoying).

Comment: Oh well, that's what I thought. Thanks for confirmation :)